# Nginx 301 redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

Пытаюсь сделать `301 redirect` с одного сайта на другой.
Как то не очень выходит.
Может кто подскажет, как правильно сделать.

`redirect` c `site.com` на `site2.com` без проблем получается, а вот если добавить уже дополнительный подкорневые вкладки, то уже возникает проблема.

Например `site.com/contact/` на `site2.com/contact/`

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    if ($host = site.ru) { # перенаправление с http на httpS
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name site.ru;
    return 301 https://site_2.ru$request_uri;
}
```

`$request_uri` - захватывает часть URL-адреса, следующая за доменным именем

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: А как можно сделать редирект если $request_uri  разные. редирект с site1.com/contact/  на site2.com/vacancy/?

Comment: согласно первой части ответа `if ($request_uri = contact) {return 301 https://site2.com/vacancy/;}`